# Command-line access for Apple Time Machine?

Tags: macos, command-line, backup, time-machine

We use Apple's Time Machine to back up our Apple 10.5.8 workstations at the office.

If I want to restore a file, I need to open up the Time Machine GUI and browse files there. The GUI is ugly eye-candy and gets in my way.

Is there a way to browse the Time Machine archive using the Mac's command-line?

I'm used to Netapps and other storage appliances. I use [backintime](http://backintime.le-web.org/) for my Ubuntu workstation. To restore a file with one of those systems, you can restore a file with a simple command like:

```
cp .snapshot/daily.0/filename.txt .
```

or

```
cp /backup/backintime/20100611-000002/backup/etc/shadow /etc/shadow
```

Is there an equivalent for Apple's Time Machine?

Comment: An intermediate solution would be to use Finder to browse the Time Machine backups just like a regular folder.

Comment: @fideli : You said we can browse Time Machine in the finder. I didn't realize this was possible. It also turns out we can browse the Time Machine folder using the commandline! For example, I can a backup of `~/.vimrc` at `/Volumes/TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/$HOSTNAME/Latest/$USERNAME/Users/mydirectory/.vimrc`.

Comment: @fideli : I think you answered my question. Go ahead an put in your answer below, mention something about 'command-line' and collect your prize!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer. An intermediate solution would be to use Finder to browse the Time Machine backups just like a regular folder. If you want to browse it in the command line, drag the folder from the Finder to the Terminal window so that you don't need to hunt through the many levels of directories that Time Machine sets up. Enjoy!

Comment: how do you drag a folder from Finder to Terminal while browsing a Time Machine backup?

Answer (score 11):

Restoring a backup from command-line can be done with the [`tmutil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) command:

```
tmutil restore <complete path to snapshot> <path to restore>
```

For example:

```
sudo tmutil restore /Volumes/TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/Server/2013-03-18-002707/Boot\ HD/Users/me/Documents/loveletter.doc loveletter.doc
```

Will restore your love letter from the backup on March 18th.

Comment: Actually, `tmutil` is not even needed to operate on the stuff in `/Volumes/TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb`.

Comment: Maybe you can use raw files copy from `Backups.backupdb`, but as being prudent I prefer using appropriate tools, you never know...

Comment: I think a straight ```cp``` would not strip the timemachine metadata from the restored files.   So , yes, better to use tmutil.

Don't know whether copying using the Finder would strip them.